# Internal Microphone not working in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with dual boot on Asus GL503GE. I encountered a very strange issue today. My internal microphone stopped working suddenly. I tried some other solutions posted on similar questions but none of them work. After reinstalling sound drivers, my internal microphone is still not working. Strangely, when I insert pin in audio jack, my internal microphone works. This is a bit strange, my external microphone should work when I put audio jack. I am attaching screenshots of both audio jack not plugged in and audio jack plugged in.

When the jack is plugged in, it shows only internal microphone. When it is not plugged in, it shows both internal and external microphone. Internal micophone does not work when jack is not plugged in but works when jack is plugged in. This is quite the opposite scenario.

Audio jack not plugged in:

[image: Audio jack not plugged in]

and

Audio jack plugged in:

[image: Audio jack plugged in]

Kindly assist me to solve this problem. I am not very familiar with audio drivers for Linux.

Comment: Maybe they can help over at pulseaudio https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/pulseaudio-discuss They tend to be friendly and helpful and the developers are there.